# Can not fetch data using Alamofire?

Tags: ios, django, swift3, get, alamofire

I am trying to fetch data in my iOS app from my Django backend. In postman if I perform a GET request on the following **URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/places/categories** with the params being `Key:"Authorization" Value: "Bearer access_token".`I get a JSON response.

Inside my app I am doing something like this with the help of Alamofire:

```
let access_token  = "123"
let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer" + access_token]

Alamofire.request(self.categoriesUrl, method: .get, parameters:nil,encoding: JSONEncoding.default,headers: headers).response { response in
            print("Request: \(response.request)")
            print("Response: \(response.response)")
            print("Error: \(response.error)")

            if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Data: \(utf8Text)")
            }
        }
```

I get an error saying **Authorization Credentials were not provided**. I understand this and it asks me to pass in the parameters but the parameters just need a token. So I do something like this:

```
let access_token  = "123"
let params = ["Authorization": "Bearer" + access_token]

Alamofire.request(self.categoriesUrl, method: .get, parameters:params,encoding: JSONEncoding.default,headers: nil).response { response in
            print("Request: \(response.request)")
            print("Response: \(response.response)")
            print("Error: \(response.error)")

            if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Data: \(utf8Text)")
            }
        }
```

It waits for a while but fails to fetch the data with the following error:

```
Response: nil
Error: Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x61800004b0d0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/places/categories/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/places/categories/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.})
Data:
```

**EDIT1:**
[image: POST MAN SCREENSHOT]

Comment: I guess mostly this error is due to not connected to the internet , please check your internet connection,

Comment: It is not because of the internet. Postman works fine and curl request also

Comment: Are you sure that headers is nil, can you show the post man request, may be ["Authorization": "Bearer" + access_token] are headers and not params

Comment: I have edited the post. You can have a look at the screenshot

Comment: @user1000 I must remind you that I know that the header is being passed and when I pass this as headers inside swift. It will give "Credentials not provided error" that is when parameters is nil. I wrote both scenarios. You can read the question again

Comment: May be this is very silly but in post man , there is a space between Bearer and token "Bearer " + yourToken, anyhow its an observation..:)

Comment: Yeah. I tried that too. Instead of using keyword I hardcoded the access_token with just one space but it does not work. We have to provide something in "parameters" but I am not sure what

Comment: Can you please show me the curl command also ?

Comment: What are you sending in the Body of postman request?

Comment: @user1000 Curl Command: curl -H "Authorization:Bearer wwHRZL5pcEuZgC8pb0fNgKNgNfj0cP" -X GET "http://localhost:8000/api/places/categories/" and nothing in the body. Its just the authorization token

Comment: Please check the answer, see if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to fix, I guess you are using iOS10 or later version of OS. So instead of calling [http](http://%20http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/places/categories) , just call [https](http://%20https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/places/categories), which means the API calling protocol has been changed to **http** to **https** in iOS10 and later.

Comment: Where exactly should I do that? You mean in the url I am requesting?

Comment: yes,  instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/places/categories, calls  https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/places/categories

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here :

`let params = ["Authorization": "Bearer" + access_token]`

You're missing a space after Bearer.

Comment: Whatever I do, my parameters can not be nil? Why is that? You can see the postman screenshot i posted. So what do i pass in the params?