# Why do I get nil in my Collection View Cell?

Tags: ios, api, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I am using Alamofire but in that case when I debug the Alamofire code does not execute and now I tried manually creating the url and setting the headers and then calling my API URL.

My collection view class is as follows.

```
//
//  CategoryViewController.swift
//  iRate
//
//  Created by Ammar Khan on 16/08/2017.
//  Copyright © 2017 theistudio. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import SDWebImage

class CategoryViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var catArr:[String] = []
    var catImage:[String] = []

    let categoriesUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/places/categories"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

       loadCatList()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for:indexPath) as! CategoryCell
        print("Reached over here \(self.catArr.count)")
        cell.categoryName.text = self.catArr[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func loadCatList(){
        let networkSession = URLSession.shared

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: self.categoriesUrl )!)

        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let dataTask = networkSession.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            print("Data downloaded")

            let jsonReadable = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

            print(jsonReadable!)
            do{

                let json = JSON(jsonReadable!)

                for (_,json):(String, JSON) in json {
                    let catName  = json["category_name"].stringValue
                    let catImage = json["image"].stringValue

                    self.catArr.append(catName)
                    self.catImage.append(catImage)
                }
            }
            catch{
                print("we have a JSON exception")
            }
        }
        //
        dataTask.resume()
        print("Downloading data")
    }

    func getCount(){
        print(self.catArr.count)
    }
}
```

I have tried various methods to add data to my dictionaries but I failed and it is giving me nil. I am not sure what am I doing wrong over here.

PS: This is not what I want to retrieve and is just for testing purpose therefore receiving just two values and adding them to dict.

**Final Result:**

As the answer suggested below was one of the problems and after that the way I was receiving data and appending them into my arrays was some how wrong so replacing the following code inside my do statement made it work.

```
let json = JSON(data!)

print("The json data is \(json)")

for (_,json):(String, JSON) in json {

    let catName = json["category_name"].stringValue
    print("The catImage is \(catName)")
    let catImage = json["image"].stringValue
    self.catArr.append(catName)
    self.catImage.append(catImage)
}

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving nil because network call is async, so when your table is displayed it is nil at that moment , and when the data comes you do not reload collectionview, so you need to add the following after for-in loop of JSON

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Update:

You should return the number of items as the number of elements in your datasource, which in this case is self.catArr, so modify your code as follows:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.catArr.count
}
```

Comment: I have pasted this inside my do statement right after the for loop. The problem is still not solved. As soon the app launches it crashes and gives me an index out of bound. It is first loading the cellForItemAt function and it breaks over there as the data has not been loaded yet

Comment: @indexOutOfBounds please check my updated answer, and give your feedback

Comment: For testing purposes I had the sections being returned 2 but it solved the error. Thank you for that but the problem stays the same. The cellforItemAt function does not execute therefore when the app launches nothing is displayed. Count still stays 0.

Comment: @indexOutOfBounds It is not showing the data because at the start of the app you have no elements in the arr, you need to populate the array at the start, since your loadCatList method is an async network call, so it takes some time to load the data, hope it helps

Comment: I am populating the array while downloading the data inside my loadCatList() function ? Should i call the function in my viewDidLoad() ? I have to populate them after downloading my data and that is what I am doing. I have debugged it and it returns count as 0 even after the data downloaded has been called. You see the data printed in the console and after that count as 0

Comment: @indexOutOfBounds Are you reloading the tableview, the first part of my answer

Comment: @indexOutOfBounds if you want your service to get data only one time when the viewcontroller's view loads then you should put your loadChatList() method call in viewDidLoad and if you want it to call every time the view did appear on the screen then you can leave it inside the viewDidAppear method, hope it helps

Comment: Yeah I know that but I debugged and actually after getting the online data I was not fetching the values correctly and the loop was also wrong. It is working fine now. i will update my question how i resolved it. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @indexOutOfBounds good work, congrats and please give feedback on this answer also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724551/can-not-fetch-data-using-alamofire/45726523#45726523  , have you solved this problem?

Comment: I was unable to resolve it therefore I moved on and removed the permissions to at least learn something but at the end of the day I do have to pass that token and fetch the data. Right now I had removed the permissions so that I could access it without token.